# How do I extend a Model in ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

It can be done in 'normal' Ember this way:

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Soldier = App.Person.extend({
  rank: DS.attr('string')
});
```

How can I achieve this in Ember-cli? I have no idea how to access the raw type of Person.

Answer (score 18):

```
import Person from "./person";

export default Person.extend({
  rank: DS.attr('string')
});
```

in a file named `soldier.js`.
I think that should do it.

Comment: glad to hear - feel free to accept it as the answer

Comment: In ember cli, the objects get their name from the file name.